# How can I export a cylinder from Blender to Unity 3D to be like a Unity 3D cylinder?

Tags: unity-game-engine, blender

In [Unity 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unity_(game_engine)) I make *GameObject* → *3D Object* → *Cylinder. And this cylinder has the components: *Cylinder* (Mesh Filter), *Capsule Collider*, and *Mesh Renderer*. I can add the last two components to my exported cylinder from [Blender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_%28software%29), but I can't add the Cylinder (Mesh Filter) component. What is Cylinder (Mesh Filter)? Is it just a Mesh Filter component?

Now I have some problems. I created some Cylinders in Blender. All of them I did using *Knife Project*. And the last step was to click on *Delete* → *Faces*. If I'm not clicking on *Delete* and make delete faces, it will not cut the hole.

The first problem is in the first cylinder I created in Blender. I cut a simple circle hole, and it's working fine exported it to Unity 3D. But the next cylinders I exported for some reason, when I'm looking at them from the front, are hollow. I see the other side outside, but if I'm moving around from the back, it's not hollow. I am not sure why.

In this screenshot are the cylinders I exported and they are in Unity 3D. The one that is fine is on the left. The others on the right hollow like. The hole cut was to the other side, but if I will look from behind, it's not open in the back:

[image: Front]

Back:

[image: Back]

The cylinders on the right I changed the circle. The one on the left I didn't change; it only rotated it.

My main goal in the end is to create a cylinder in Blender with just a hole I can walk inside with my character in Unity 3D.

The on the left seems fine, but the hole is too small and high, so I can't walk in.

In Blender it looks fine only in Unity. It looks hollow side to side from the front:

[image: Cylinder blender]

Comment: Are you sure the walls of the latter cylinders have any thickness? If they don't have faces on the inside of your cylinder, they'll be invisible due to Unity performing back-face culling.

Comment: @Serlite i added now a screenshot to my question of the blender how the cylinder looks like there. Seems fine only in unity it looks hollow side to side. thickness you mean using solidify modifier and change there the Thickn ?

Comment: As in, ensure the wall of the cylinder isn't just as thick as a single plane. If it doesn't have any actual thickness to it, it means that there are probably no faces pointing inside your cylinder, so Unity won't render anything when the camera points inside it due to back-face culling.

Comment: @Serlite right thank you it's working now.  Now i need to find how to make that the character will not walk through the object in unity. I can use capsule collider but then i can't walk in. Any ideas some lead direction what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to flip your *Normals* in Blender. That is the reason you are seeing this effect in the whole of your cylinder. Follow [this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/29132/how-do-i-flip-normals-on-this-model) for the inside *faces* of your cylinder.

Comment: Observing your first image I can now see that you have made the first cylinder hollow inside, so `blender` flips your normals for you, but if its not hollow as in the rest of them, you have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the normals.

Unity does not render backfaces. Faces have front and back sides, and game engines don't render back sides by default for optimization reasons. Your mesh is not watertight, and from the hole you are seeing the back side of the faces of the other side.

The first cylinder looks fine, because it has volume, so it's watertight and its backfaces are hidden inside it.

**Solution 1:** in Unity, set the cylinder's material as double-sided. This will tell Unity to not disregard backfaces that use this material.

**Solution 2:** in Blender, extrude all faces of the cylinder a bit so that it has some volume to it. This way, the mesh will be watertight, so there will be no backfaces visible (backfaces will be hidden inside the model).

**Regarding collision problems;**

if you want a character to be able to walk inside the cylinder, but not through its walls, do solution 2 and put a "mesh collider component" on the cylinder in Unity. This will make each face collideable instead of wrapping a simple 3D object around the model as the collider.